# What is the default regular expression character class for the `$unsafe_chars` arg to `HTML::Entities::encode_entities`?

Tags: regex, perl, html-entities, character-class

According to the [`HTML::Entities` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aEntities), the second argument to `encode_entities`:

> The unsafe characters is specified using the regular expression character class syntax (what you find within brackets in regular expressions).
>
> The default set of characters to encode are control chars, high-bit chars, and the <, &, >, ' and " characters.

However the page doesn't provide an example of what the equivalent argument would be for the default set. I'd like to make a minor adjustment to the set of unsafe chars without regressing.

What regex character class would be equivalent to «control chars, high-bit chars, and the <, &, >, ' and "» which I can use as a starting point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [module source](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aEntities), it looks like:

```
/([^\n\r\t !\#\$%\(-;=?-~])/
```

From this bit in `encode_entities`:

```
# Encode control chars, high bit chars and '<', '&', '>', ''' and '"'
$$ref =~ s/([^\n\r\t !\#\$%\(-;=?-~])/$char2entity{$1} || num_entity($1)/ge;
```

A non-negated class:

```
/([\x00-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f-\xff<&>'"])/
```

Comment: I actually looked at the source, and didn't think a negated character class would work as an argument to the method - but it seems I was wrong! Nonetheless, I'm going to wait on the green check - I'd prefer a non-negated character class.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen Why does it matter if the character class is negated? If you don't want to encode a specific character, add it to the list; if you do want to encode it, remove it. Note that ranges are possible (it already includes `\(-;` and `?-~`).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Thanks! I didn't figure out that those were ranges and assumed I was lacking in my regex-fu, but it makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a default substitution regex:

```
s/([^\n\r\t !\#\$%\(-;=?-~])/$char2entity{$1} || num_entity($1)/ge
```

https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities

Comment: That's exactly the same answer Jim Davis gave.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Sorry, I was slower. :(